# Using Automator to save text to a SPECIFIED text file (not a new file)

Tags: applescript, automator

I know that there's a way to use Automator to save text to a new text file.
 But I want an Automator application that saves the text from clipboard to a GIVEN text file (by editing it, i.e. adding in the next line). Applescript would be okay too. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an **Automator** *workflow/application* using a **Run Shell Script** *action* with:

```
/usr/bin/pbpaste >> '/path/to/filename.txt'
echo >> '/path/to/filename.txt'
```

---

**Notes:**

Check out the manual page for: `pbpaste`

You can read the *manual page* for *`command`* in **Terminal** by typing *`command`* and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

The `echo >> '/path/to/filename'` line adds a single *line feed* to the end of the *file* after the pasted text. You can add addition lines for more *line feeds* if you so choose.

In place of the `echo` *command* you can also use, e.g.:

```
printf '\n' >> '/path/to/filename.txt'
```

Adding additional `\n` for more *line feeds*, e.g. `'\n\n'`.

If you update the *file* while it's opened, it is not doing to show the updated contents, you need to close/reopen the *file* to see additional updates to it.

---

[image]

---

If you want to do it with **AppleScript**, then in place of the **Run Shell Script** *action*, use a **Run AppleScript** *action* with the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* wish uses a slightly modified *handler* from [Reading and Writing Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReadandWriteFiles.html):

```
set myFilename to (path to documents folder) & "Clipboard Text.txt"

set cbText to ((the clipboard) as text) & linefeed & linefeed

writeTextToFile(cbText, myFilename, false)


on writeTextToFile(theText, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)
    try
        -- Convert the file to a string
        set theFile to theFile as string
        -- Open the file for writing
        if theFile contains "/" then
            set theOpenedFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        else
            set theOpenedFile to open for access file theFile with write permission
        end if
        -- Clear the file if content should be overwritten
        if overwriteExistingContent is true then set eof of theOpenedFile to 0
        -- Write the new content to the file
        write theText to theOpenedFile starting at eof
        -- Close the file
        close access theOpenedFile
        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing was successful
        return true
        -- Handle a write error
    on error
        -- Close the file
        try
            close access file theFile
        end try
        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing failed
        return false
    end try
end writeTextToFile
```

---

**Notes:**

The *handler* from the linked **Apple** support document was modified to handle both **POSIX** and **HFS+** *file paths*.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the application/workflow?

Comment: @Righter, Screenshot added.

Comment: It's not working for me; the text file isn't changing

Comment: @Righter, RE: "It's not working for me; the text file isn't changing" --  What I can tell you is that I've tested the _code_ from both the **Run Shell Script** _action_ and the **Run AppleScript** _action_ in the updated answer and both work for me without issues. You will need to provide more details to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Ok, here are the screenshots. Application: https://imgur.com/B9DZcdG  Desktop file icon: https://imgur.com/PcLmnMK  Text file before running app: https://imgur.com/8je4q5b  Confirmation for running app: https://imgur.com/A3ZhT8u  Permission for accessing files: https://imgur.com/Q3tesE0  Text file after running app: https://imgur.com/TuUfN2F

Comment: @Righter, First of all, your **Automator** _workflow_ is not the same as mine!  Mine use a single _action_, a **Run Shell Script** _action_ (or a **Run AppleScript** _action_) and the defined _file_ is a _plain text file_, not a **Rich Text** (.rtf) _file_ . Secondly, you do not need to use a **Get Contents of Clipboard** _action_ as that is what the `pbpaste` _command_ in the **Run Shell Script** _action_ is doing.  Additionally, if you update the _file_ while it's opened, it is not doing to show the updated _contents_, you need to close/reopen the _file_ to see additional updates to it.

Comment: That finally worked, thanks a lot! I'm not at all familiar with the scripts :)

Comment: @Righter, I've edited the  _handler_ from the linked **Apple** support document  to handle both **POSIX** and **HFS+** _file paths_.